# how to changge /shop/ URL to /products/ URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good day!

In Woocommerce the default URL for listing products is `www.site.com/shop/` I would like to change it to `www.site.com/products/` as we won't be necessarily selling but would just be showcasing products.

We would like to change `/shop/` to `/products/`. I've tried to change the slug in the Product page but some error do occur.

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visit "General" -> "Permalinks" section in your admin panel, it will reset permalink structure and error message should disapperar.

Comment: Nope. Changed Product Permalinks to the Custom Base of "/products", but when I navigate to /products, I get a 404.  Only /shop works, no matter what I change in the Permalinks page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to change the URL from shop to products. you need to go to the pages their you go to the page shop open that page. their you see the option of the edit URL from their you can change the URL of your site from shop to products.

Comment: I did that got:
`( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function is_visible() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\Foxy\woocommerce\content-product.php on line 25`

Comment: I don't have a page called "shop", yet /shop still works, so this comment is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to rename **shop** page to **product**
Go to Pages> Edit shop page > change permalink to **product** > Update
You might even rename title to product list or something